# perform some action when usb is detected c#

Tags: c#

i have been developing an application and i want to detect usb devices(MASS STORAGE) now that i have done but what i need to do is to capture that message and dont pass it to the windows. i want to ask a password and if that's ok then i want to pass the message to the windows otherwise discard it,,,how can i accomplish that,,,>

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
switch(m.Msg)
{
case Win32.WM_DEVICECHANGE: OnDeviceChange(ref m); break;
}
base.WndProc (ref m);
}

void OnDeviceChange(ref Message msg)
{
int wParam = (int)msg.WParam;
if (wParam == Win32.DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL)
{
    label1.Text = "Arrival";
    //MessageBox.Show("" + wParam);
    //msg = Message.Create(new IntPtr(),1,new IntPtr(),new IntPtr());
}
else if (wParam == Win32.DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE) label1.Text =
 "Remove";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent windows to detect the hardware, unless your software is running under the **ring 0** (or 1, can't remember) protection level as a low level application.

This can only be achieved with a low level programming (C, ASM), not C#. The IL language will never be capable of doing things like you want to do.

Anyway, the thing you are doing is nothing but skipping the message to the base class of the Form, not more. The system will continue anyway to send messages like this to other applications no matter if you want it or not.

Comment: i just want to pull the message from message que of operating system so that windows wont know abut the device... that aint possible in c#...? if no then can u guide me to a c library perhaps that i can use in c#

Comment: @user1403207 I doubt there is a open free downloadable library for such things. I guess you should [seek](http://google.com) for it on your own.